# R shinydashboard - change height of valueBox

Tags: r, shinydashboard

Given a `shinydashboard`

**ui.R**

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

dashboardPage(

    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        valueBoxOutput(outputId = "vb")
    )
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

function(input, output, session) {

    output$vb <- renderValueBox({
        valueBox(subtitle = "Hello", 
                         value = "hi", 
                         width = 6,
                         color="blue"
        )
    })
}
```

**Question**

Is it possible to change the height of the `valueBox`?

I've tried using `tags` but can't get them to work so I'm obviously missing something:

```
dashboardPage(

    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
    #   tags$head(tags$style("#vb{height:500px}"))
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        # tags$head(tags$style("#vb{height:500px}")),

        # div(style="height: 500px",
        #       valueBoxOutput(outputId = "vb")
        # )
        valueBoxOutput(outputId = "vb")
    )
)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It turns out I wasn't referencing the value box correctly; I need to use the `.small-box` class:

```
dashboardPage(

    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".small-box {height: 50px}"))),
        valueBoxOutput(outputId = "vb")
    )
)
```

Comment: Is there a similar way I can also change the font size? Tried 'tags$p(tags$style(HTML(".small-box {font-size: 10px}")))' but does not work

Comment: For the font size, you can do that change on the server side in the `renderValueBox` by wrapping the text in the `valueBox` in ` tags$p()` with the argument `style = "font-size: 80%;"` and setting the percentage as the desired font size