# Adjust the height of infoBox in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a very basic infoBox like this, and want to adjust the height as the current height is just way too much for what I am incorporating.

Any idea how I can do it? I tried what was suggested here: [r shinydashboard - change height of valueBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422946/r-shinydashboard-change-height-of-valuebox). But, that is not having any change.

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id = 'sidebarmenu',
              menuItem('About', tabName = 'about'))
  )

about <- tabItem('about', fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
      infoBoxOutput('age')
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
   about 
  )  
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = 'My App'
  ),
  sidebar = sidebar,
  body = body
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$age <- renderInfoBox({
    infoBox('Age: ', 50, icon = icon('list'), width = 6)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to apply some CSS rules.

```
body <- dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.info-box {min-height: 45px;} .info-box-icon {height: 45px; line-height: 45px;} .info-box-content {padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;}'))),
    tabItems(
        about 
    )  
)
```

Comment: Works like charm. Just wish I don't have to deal with this type of code and instead had a parameter to `infoBox` called `height`. :)

Comment: There are a few Shiny UI elements that supports either `height` or `style="height:500px;"`. But in this case, the height is actually determined by several elements (the infobox and the icon).

Comment: @Xiongbing Jin, thank you for the tags$head command, it helped me also with my requirement, please help me with this link which needs some slight tweaks.                   
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47154749/changing-the-width-height-and-alignment-of-the-shiny-widgets-in-r